# vim in mac c-f doesn't page down

Tags: macos, vim

Using mac book pro, OSX 10.13.3, iterms, vim(installed with homebrew)

I want to default key `c-f`, `c-b` for `page down` and `page up`

but when I use `c-f` or `c-b`, It doesn't work but just shows `controlP` like below capture.

[image: push down <code>c-f</code>]
[image: push down <code>c-b</code>]
When using `iterms`, default mac `terminal`, `macvim`, same issue occur.

There is no map about `c-f` and `c-b` in `.vimrc`. And I reinstalled vim, but same.

How can I use default key map?

Comment: are you sure there is no mapping? what does `:verbose map <c-f>` say?

Comment: hm... It says    `<C-F>         <Plug>(ctrlp)
        Last set from ~/.vim_runtime/sources_non_forked/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.v
im`

Comment: I don't remember installing this... what is the `ctrlp.vim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, it is the `ctrl-p` plugin which does that.
But you can't just remap the command in your `vimrc` because the plugin is sourced after your `vimrc` so your mapping will be overwritten.

It would be possible to remap it in an `autocmd` (see `:h autocmd`) or in an file in the after-directory (`:h after-directory`)

But since `ctrl-p` is written as recommended, there is a setting to control the mapping:

```
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
```

This works in your `vimrc`

Have a look here: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got it mapped from somewhere else. You can unmap it or remap it in your .vimrc file. Did you happen to copy someone else's configuration? I don't know what the .vim_runtime directory is.

A quick google shows this [repo](https://github.com/amix/vimrc). Are you using that?

I've copied other people's vimrcs before but still wouldn't suggest it. It leads to problems like this BUT I could be totally wrong in what you're doing here.

Cheers!

Comment: Although still I don't remember installing, I think I installed that repo. After remove that directory, page down works!

Comment: Actually zou can't unmap or remap it in the `vimrc` since the plugin is sourced *after* the `vimrc`

Comment: Yes, since we have now figured it comes from a plugin, @DoktorOSwaldo is correct. By default plugins are sourced after the vimrc. There are ways around this but by default this is the case.

Comment: No bad feelings, but you should not change the source order to source your `vimrc` after the plugins as your comment implies. Please use the `after` directory!